# Application not updating after overwriting existing files

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am having an issue trying to deploy updates to my siliverlight application. For some users, not all, in order for the page to update they have to clear their browsers local cache. Refreshing will not update the page, and they will run into issues as it appears to use a local version against the updated server.

Is there any way to force the clients to update their local copy when I make changes?

Comment: Put a fake querystring with a custom variable behind the xap url in the index site. Everytime you update the site, change the variable. We use version numbers for that. `myapplicaton.xap?version=1`

Comment: This wouldn't work for users who bookmarked the site though correct?

Comment: That doesn't matter because the xap url is not bookmarked. The xap url is only used in the index.aspx.

Comment: Sometimes I have to do an IISReset on the server.  Haven't had to to look into why.

Comment: @JBrooks Probably with IIS 6, because we had the same issue sometimes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main page e.g. `index.aspx` you can put a fake query string in the value of the following line:

```
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/MyApplication.xap?version=1.0.0.0" />
```

When you update your application, change the version number to e.g. `1.0.0.1`
This is how we force the client to download the newest `.xap` file.
There is no issue with bookmarking since this url will never appear in the address bar.
The client would instead be bookmarking something like `http://myurl/index.aspx.`

Comment: I will give this a shot tonight and accept it if it works, looks solid though. Thank you very much. I misread first comment as .aspx for some reason, not xap.

Comment: @JeremyK It could be another variation like `MVC` of course. I just assumed `aspx` for no good reason :).

Comment: nonono it is. I just read value="ClientBin/MyApplication.xap?version=1.0.0.0" as value="ClientBin/MyApplication.aspx?version=1.0.0.0"   read it too fast. So far all looks good, thank you silver